# How to create assemblies with transitive dependencies in Maven multi-module project

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

My Parent POM

```
<modules>
    <module>test.distribution.module1</module>
    <module>test.distribution.module2</module>
    <module>test.distribution.dist</module>
</modules>
...
...
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-distribution</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

POM of module 1 and module 2 are trivial (with start scripts in default location). Below is POM of distribution module,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abhishek</groupId>
        <artifactId>test.distribution.module1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abhishek</groupId>
        <artifactId>test.distribution.module2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is assembly.xml in distribution module

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>bin</id>
<!-- Specifies that our binary distribution is a zip package -->
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <includes>
            <include>com.abhishek:test.distribution.module1</include>
        </includes>
        <sources>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</directory>
                    <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>README*</include>
                        <include>LICENSE*</include>
                        <include>NOTICE*</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/site</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>docs</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
    <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <includes>
            <include>com.abhishek:test.distribution.module2</include>
        </includes>
        <sources>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</directory>
                    <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>README*</include>
                        <include>LICENSE*</include>
                        <include>NOTICE*</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/site</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>docs</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

Everything is OK here, but "mvn clean package" results in

```
test.distribution.dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip  
--test.distribution.dist-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-bin  
  --test.distribution.module1  
    --lib  
      --module1.jar  
    --start.bat  
  --test.distribution.module2  
    --lib  
      --module2.jar  
    --start.bat
```

The only thing that I want is to put module1's transitive dependencies in test.distribution.module1/lib folder and same for module 2.

Another thing is, I want to know when to use moduleset over dependencyset in assembly.

I would appriciate any best practice advise regarding myy project structure or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to achieve this but dont know if this is the prefferred option or not.

I added the below snippet in parent POM

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

It copies the transitive dependencies of every modules into its own target/lib directory. Then I added beow snippet into assembly.xml' every moduleset

```
<fileSet>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
```